# Multiple submit javascript - page being refreshed

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to javascript and i have a Form with multiple submit function using javascript and php being refreshed. I can  view the alerts but rather than transferring to new page, every time the page is being refreshed and not transferred.
 My Java Script:

```
<script>
function submitFunction(i)
{
    if(i==1){
        alert("Transferring to page1.php");
        document.flight_select.action="page1.php";
        document.flight_select.submit();
    }
    if(i==2){
        alert("Transferring to searchflights.php");
        document.flight_select.action="search_flights.php";
        document.flight_select.submit();
    }
}
</script>
```

This is my PHP Code:

```
echo "
    <form id=\"flight_select\"  method=\"POST\">; //Some formatting code follows this for displaying table;
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"2\" >
            <input type=\"submit\" value = \"< New Search\" onClick=\"submitFunction(2)\";/></td>
            <td colspan=\"3\"><center>"."<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Make Booking for selected flight >\" onClick=\"submitFunction(1)\"/>"."</center>
            </td></tr>";
```

Comment: well you have a form submitting and you set the action and submit the form again?

Comment: Well, there are two form displayed on the form, if user clicks the "New Search Button", he has to be redirected to search_flights.php(the same page with values reset) and if he clicks Make Booking he has to be redirected to another page. I made a function submitFunction and am passing the values 1 and 2.  In my case the alerts are popping up correctly but I am not being transferred. I havent used action tag in html as I am setting action and submit using javascript. Hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: But you are clicking on a submit button and submit buttons submit...

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You did not cancel the original submission that will be triggered by the click. Using `return false` is one way to do cancel the default click event handler, so that it does not submit your form before your submission can go through. In your code, the easiest way to do this is `onClick="submitFunction(2);return false"`.

Additionally, consider not doing `onClick="javascriptcode"`, but attaching handlers from JavaScript side, and also not using `echo` to output HTML, to maintain separation of code and presentation.

Comment: Thanks for resolving the question. I modified the code and am posting the final code below. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
As per your suggestion, I modified the code to look something like this and that resolved my issue:

<script>
function submitFunction(i)
{
    if(i==1){
        alert("Page1.php");
        document.getElementById("flight_select").action="page1.php"
        document.getElementById("flight_select").submit();
    }
    if(i==2){
        alert("searchflights.php");
        document.getElementById("flight_select").action="search_flights.php"
        document.getElementById("flight_select").submit();
    }

}
</script>

<html>
<head><title>Multiple submit test</title></head>
<body>
<form id="flight_select" method="POST">
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"/>
<input type="submit" value="Click for page1.php!" onClick="submitFunction(1);return false;"/>
<input type="submit" value="Click for search_flights!" onClick="submitFunction(2);return false;"/> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```